# Steam mop hardwood floors

Tags: drywall, construction, hardwood

How bad would it be to steam mop hardwood floors once? I got new flooring through my house and then had to have a lot of drywall work done. The floors were not covered (I didn't know better). I've washed them 3 times with a mop and still have a film coating them, and some in the cracks.

I would only do steam mop once, not regularly.

Comment: hardwood will not like steam

Answer (score 0):

Using a steam mop on hardwood floors, even just once, can potentially cause damage to the flooring. Steam mops generate high heat and moisture, which can penetrate the wood and cause it to warp, swell, or buckle. Additionally, the excessive moisture can weaken the finish and lead to discoloration or staining.

Considering that you have already washed the floors three times with a regular mop and still have a film coating them, it is advisable to avoid using a steam mop. Instead, try alternative methods to remove the film and clean the floors effectively. You can use a hardwood floor cleaner recommended by the manufacturer or a mixture of vinegar and water (in a 1:10 ratio) to gently clean the surface. Be sure to wring out the mop or cloth thoroughly to avoid excessive moisture.

If the film persists, you may need to consult a professional hardwood floor cleaner or contact the manufacturer for specific cleaning instructions. It's important to take proper care of your hardwood floors to maintain their appearance and longevity.